# Are byte slices of utf8 also utf8?

Tags: utf-8

Given a slice of bytes that is valid utf8, is it true that any sub-slice of such slice is also valid `utf8`?

In other words, given `b1: [u8]` that is valid `utf8`, can I assume that

`b2 = b1[i..j]` is valid utf8 for any `i,j : i<j`?

If not, what would be the counter-example?

Comment: no? So `π` in hex is `cf80` , so if you slice `cf` and `80`, both are invalid. (?) `sub-slice of such slice` Is the slicing done on _bytes_ boundaries?

Comment: Yeap, correct answer. For some reason I was thinking about complex examples. Could you convert it to an answer?

Comment: Basically the rule is to cut only before either a single-byte character (i.e. <= 0x7F) *or* a start-byte (>= 0x80 && <= 0xBF). Then correctness would be preserved (i.e. the result can  still be incorrect if the input is incorrect). Note that this preserves *only* UTF-8 encoding correctness. Cutting Unicode strings after arbitrary unicode codepoints can easily lead to meaningless strings (for example cutting between a character and its modifier codepoints).

Comment: One main feature of UTF-8 is to synchronize: at any given byte one can read just a few bytes to then tell at which a new character begins. Which also means cutting anywhere in there would produce bytes that don't synchronize anymore. A technique that is/was common in MPEG, ISDN and many other systems for decades already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what would be the counter-example?

Any code point that encodes as more than 1 byte. For example `π` in hex is `cf80`, and slicing it in the middle produces two (separate) invalid UTF-8 strings.